Changing package in xcode project not changing dependency
I have a dependency in package.swift defined like this:
dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/agithub/project", branch: "main")
    ],

but when I change it to a different forked version and branch
dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/mygithub/my-project", branch: "my-branch")
    ],

xcode doesn't seem to update this. I tried everything like deleting local caches, rebuild. I can even put a non-existent branch name in the package.swift file and it doesn't change it. Also it seems when I look in the package content folder and open the project.pbxproj, the main branch package still seems to be there.
How to have it use the updated dependency package?

Deleting the Package.resolved has no incidence?

no effect, i deleted all local files and it still doesnt update the dependency

Did you try File -> Packages -> Reset Package Caches ?

Apart from removing the .build folder and deleting the Package.resolved file, you can try a few other things:

Delete derived data

Go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and delete the contents of this folder.
You can also do this from Xcode by going to Xcode > Preferences > Locations and clicking the arrow next to the Derived Data path, then deleting the folder.

Clean the build folder

In Xcode, go to Product > Clean Build Folder (or press Shift + Command + K).
